# Are PDF files guaranteed to store plain text consistently?

Tags: pdf

PDF files are notorious for their inconsistent storage of text formatting: If you write some text in Word/Writer, apply bold, italic, etc., print it to PDF, then open this PDF in Acrobat Reader DC or any other viewer and copy the text out back to Word, odds are that you'll see at least some formatting lost. Often as not, you just get plain text.

My question is: Can I trust this plain text to be exactly the same (same Unicode characters in the same order) as the original or can it, too, become mangled in some inobvious way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, PDF intentionally changes text to "page description format", i.e., PDF. E.G., even though an *unbroken* paragraph is inserted into a PDF, in the conversion to page format, line break characters are often inserted at the end of each line as it would appear on that page.

For example, in this screen shot from a PDF reader, an apparently unbroken paragraph,

[image: PDF screenshot]

when viewed as text in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/),

[image: PDF text in Notepad++]

shows carriage return/linefeed pairs at the end of all except the last line.

Converting text to PDF is easy; going back from PDF to text is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can guarantee is that visually the PDF will *look* the same as the input document. PDF is a format for document distribution, not interchanging from one format to another.

As an example if you have an input with textboxes written in various places that are, in theory, following on one from another in Word you cannot guarantee that the blocks of text will be linked or even in the same order in your output, especially when passed through or saved from other PDF viewers or editors that may be able to "optimise" the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to covert files back from PDF,  machine created PDF files are the best bet and this often works decently well.

Converting from a PDF that was a scan from a printed / paper document normally requires a great deal of intervention.

There are OCR apps that might be better for this kind of work.